# Use AWS ELB with PowerDNS

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing, amazon-elb, powerdns

**Background:** A PowerDNS is deployed on an EC2 inside a VPC. From PDNS, I added a master zone and a record CNAME pointing to ELB's DNS name.

Now from within the VPC, when I ping the ELB's DNS name, I got a private IP, but when I ping the PDNS record, I got an external IP.

**Question**: Is there anyway I can make the PDNS record to give me a private IP just like what the ELB does?

Answer (score 0):

Normally the public IP of ELB changes over time by AWS, so adding an A record wont help you much here. If you really want to do that however, you can use the [PowerDNS API](https://doc.powerdns.com/md/httpapi/README/) to add an A record.